# Can't find a Radeon R5 M230 driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, radeon

I've searched the net over and over, but I can't find the driver.

I tried installing `amdgpu-pro` from my Radeon R5 M230 driver but it wouldn't boot. So I had to uninstall it.

Can anyone help me with this? I can't get a new laptop.

Comment: Not to sound gloomy but you need to read [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04)

Comment: `amdgpu-pro` is still experimental. The default open-source driver should be enough though.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Can you please help out? I am really new at Linux and I don't know where to get that.

Comment: You already have it, it's installed by default. Depending on your hardware Ubuntu installs and uses either `radeon` or `amdgpu` .

Comment: @CelticWarrior Ah, I see. Thanks for the answer man. When I run `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`, I get [this](http://imgur.com/a/VLhsx). It looks like the Radeon GPU is not running i.e. the integrated intel one is.

Comment: If you run `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'` the output will look better ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Ha, I see it now. Thanks man. I guess my PC is slow due to being shit overall.

Comment: @Ivan What's your PC spec? I have the R5 M230 with the i5-4200M on G510 and it feels shit on fresh Ubuntu install even though it didn't feel like that back 2.5 years ago. I am not sure if Web has now evolved and using much juice that i5 is no longer fast enough.